# Using Regex to capture data in jenkins pipeline

Tags: regex, jenkins, groovy

I want to pull apart a docker image uri inside of my Jenkins pipeline. Example uri = https://test-registry.home.imagehub.com/engineering/images/rhel:latest. I would like to break this down into 4 parts.

https://(test-registry).home.imagehub.com/(engineering/images)/(rhel):(latest)

$1 =  test-registry

$2 = engineering/images

$3 = rhel

$4 = latest

caveats $2 sometimes only has one directory level

I believe the proper regex for this is:

```
/\w+:\/\/(.*)\.[^\/]+/(.*)/(\w+):(.*)/
```

This should grab everything after the `//s` up to the first `.` (period) for $1

The `[^\/]` should move up to the / divider through the subdomains

I want the second `(.*)` to be greedy up to but not including the last / divider.

The 3rd part should grab everything after the last `/` divider and before the `:`

the 4th part should grab everything after the `:` (colon)

I did include the regex

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

I have tried a lot of different solutions to make this work in my jenkins declarative pipeline such as inline:
sReg = https://test-registry.home.imagehub.com/engineering/images/rhel:latest

pipeline

  agent

  stages

  stage ('regex')

    steps

    scripts

      def sReg = https://test-registry.home.imagehub.com/engineering/images/rhel:latest

     def registry = sReg =~ /\w+:\/\/(.*)\./
```

here I expected:

```
registry = test-registry
```

So I echo the result

```
echo registry.group(1)
```

but this gives me:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found

Which makes no sense. I have tried just getting the https with `/(\w+):/` but same result.

I tried with a class also but same result, no matches.

I would like to get all four in one shot but I will pull out each part in a separate regex if need be. At this point I would like to figure out how I can at least get a match.

I added:

import java.util.regex.Matcher

Then down in the script section I added:

def registry = Sreg =~ ///([^.]+)[^/]+/((?:[^/]+/)*[^/]+)/(.+):(.+)/

println(registry)

When I run the pipeline I get:

[Pipeline] echo

java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=//([^.]+)[^/]+/((?:[^/]+/)*[^/]+)/(.+):(.+) region=0,78 lastmatch=]

So instead of extracting the information it is equaling the pattern?

I did an echo on Sreg and it shows the uri so it should be getting the uri in my def.

Comment: Try `\/\/([^.]+)[^\/]+\/((?:[^\/]+\/)*[^\/]+)\/(.+):(.+)`. Demo on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/0opHDK/1).

Answer (score 5):

You can access groups with :

```
def sReg = "https://test-registry.home.imagehub.com/engineering/images/rhel:latest"
def registry = sReg =~ /\w+:\/\/(.*)\.[^\/]+/(.*)/(\w+):(.*)/

println registry[0] //For all groups
println registry[0][1] //For group 1
```

Sources and examples : https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-matchers-for-regular.html

Comment: When I println(registry) I get: java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=//([^.]+)[^/]+/((?:[^/]+/)*[^/]+)/(.+):(.+) region=0,78 lastmatch=] not the actual match. I added this to my original post so it is a little easier to follow.

Comment: This code in jenkins :
`def sReg = "https://test-registry.home.imagehub.com/engineering/images/rhel:latest"
def registry = sReg =~ /\w+:\/\/(.*)\./
    
println registry[0][1]`

give me :

`[Pipeline] node
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
test-registry.home.imagehub
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline`

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out my whole issue was my agent statement.

Instead of: agent { node 'slave' }

I had: agent {node 'slave'}

Once I fixed this the regex started working.

FYI

I found out also the println(registry) statement is still just the pattern matcher but now println(registry[0][1]) gives me the captured text.